# Identifiers recognition inside `do` blocks in Swift 3.1

Tags: swift, swift3, scope

Swift seems to work out identifiers recognition line by line:

```
print(fox) // Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'fox'
let fox = ""
```

However, strange thing happens inside the `do` block:

```
do {
    print(dog) // Error: Use of local variable 'dog' before its declaration
    let dog = ""
}
```

How does the compiler know that I'm going to declare `dog` after trying to print it? Is identifier recognition handled differently inside `do` blocks?

Comment: Is `fox` declared in global scope? Or is it inside of function/class/struct/etc?

Comment: @user28434 You are on a good track. `fox` is in global scope and the error is different if I move it to a function. Then it goes like this: `Use of local variable 'fox' before its declaration`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Swift compiler handles undefined identifiers differently depending on their scope.

The difference between `fox` and `dog` variables is the scope. It is not specific to `do` blocks: any kind of a block would change classification of undefined variable from "unresolved identifier" (global scope) to "local variable before declaration" (local scope).

Here are other ways to get the same error:

```
_ = {
    print(fox) // Error: Use of local variable 'fox' before its declaration
    let fox = ""
}
func foo() {
    print(fox) // Error: Use of local variable 'fox' before its declaration
    let fox = ""
}
class Bar {
    func bar() {
        print(fox) // Error: Use of local variable 'fox' before its declaration
        let fox = ""
    }
}
```

My guess for the reason of why this is happening is that the compiler waits for the end of the local scope before reporting errors, while errors in the global scope are reported right away. This is a good tradeoff, because the end of the local scope does not generally requires scanning the entire translation unit all the way to the end.

Comment: You are totally right, but it still doesn't answer the question how it's handled. If you don't declare it afterwards, you will get `Use of unresolved identifier` inside the blocks too.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on @dasblinkenlight's answer you still seem to be unsure "how it's handled", maybe this will help:

When a compiler needs to resolve an identifier it starts by searching the immediately enclosing scope, then moves to the scope enclosing that etc. until it reaches the global scope.

As part of this search it is worthwhile for the compiler to look through the *complete scope*, including that part of it past the point when the identifier it is resolving is used. (Indeed compilers are often multi-pass so the "look ahead" here may actually already have been done.) This process allows the production of an error indicating an identifier is used before its declaration.

If the search makes it all the way to the global scope without finding a match then the unresolved error is produced.

**Addendum: Not all scopes work the same way**

A *declaration* occurs within some *declaration scope*; e.g. a function body, a class, a `while` body, the global level, etc.

*Declaration scopes* nest, e.g. a statement scope within a function, a function within a class, a class within the global scope.

In *local declaration scopes*, e.g.. a function body and any nested scopes, an entity must be declared before it is used - declaration order matters.

Entities declared directly in a *type declaration scope* (class, struct, etc.) or the *global declaration scope* may be referenced *before* they are declared - declaration order does not matter. This allows mutual recursion etc.

So a error indicating an entity is used before it is declared is only possible in a local scope.

HTH

Comment: Why isn't compiler interested in letting us know that it was declared later in the global scope?

Comment: OK, could have been clearer: it doesn't need to (in Swift, this varies depending on language). The order of declarations at the global/type (class, struct etc.) level does not matter, a reference to something declared latter is fine. So at the global/type level the compiler searches the whole scope, just as with local scopes, but "use before declaration" is not an error.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment to be honest. How is that not an error? It is an error :)

Comment: @RoboRobok - Added an addendum, hopefully that makes it clearer.